# How to create Enemies class in cocos2d

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocos2d-iphone

I am using cocos2d for the iphone
I want to create a class for Enemies

see my code

```
 #import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
 #import "cocos2d.h"

 @interface Enemies : CCSprite {
      float imageHeight;
 }
 @property float imageHeight;
 +(id) enemies;
 @end


@implementation Enemies
@synthesize imageHeight;

+(id) enemies{ 
return [[[self alloc] initWithFile:@"enemy.png"] autorelease];
}
@end
```

I want the to set the imageHeight

```
float imageHeight = [enemy texture].contentSize.height;
```

so whenever I create an instance of the class Enemies I it should have imageHeight set properly?

Thanks

note: I am trying to improve [this code](http://books.google.com/books?id=9CQL8t6Eob0C&lpg=PA253&ots=Afw5LxENwT&dq=%22%40interface%20player%20%3A%20CCSprite%20%7B%22&pg=PA253#v=onepage&q=%22@interface%20player%20%3a%20CCSprite%20%7B%22&f=false)

Comment: Enimies has the property imageHeight. and image height is property

Comment: so u can directly set imageheight by creating enemies object in different class and then object.imageHeight=value u want to set . i did not get why you created +(id)enimies

Comment: but how to set imageHeight, I cant find a handler to the instance of the class! , do I have to write something like this:imageHeight = [self texture].contentSize.height; ?

Comment: k got it create yr own get accessor method for imageHeight method  in this method imageHeight=[super texture].contentSize.height;

Comment: I want imageheight to be set automatically for every instance of the class, I dont want to set it manually for every object, I hope that clarified the problem, Thanks

Comment: what about -(id)init method . it calls always when object creates in this u can set imageHeight value- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil {
    if ((self = [super init])) {
        imageHeight=[super texture].contentSize.height;
    return self;
}

Comment: but I have many enemies, it want be a good idea to set properties for every Object separately in the (id)init!, I think!

Comment: .no issue if u have more enimies object try this  -(id)init {
    if ((self = [super init])) {
        imageHeight=[super texture].contentSize.height;
    return self;
}

Answer (score 0):

ahmed, keep the `enemies` method the same, and add this to your class:

```
-(id) init { 
    if (self = [super init]) {
        float textureHeight = [enemy texture].contentSize.height;
        [self setImageHeight:textureHeight];
    }
    return self;
}
```

This will set `imageHeight` for all new instances of the `Enemies` class.

Answer (score 0):

Override initWithFile in Enemies class.
Then Inside it call, [super initWithFile passing the same Filename string]

After which you can set the imageHeight variable in the next line as the texture would have been loaded and height will be accessible.

Answer (score 0):

Cocos2d automatically sets the height of some things based on the image itself. Look for the sprite's setHeight property, it should be easy to find in the docs.

However, your question looks like it could use rewording. Your "Enemy" should be data, not related to any display (sprites) whatsoever, unless you're going to make a really small app.

Check out Beginning XNA books for nice examples of how to abstract superclass enemy and players, if you can use C# and translate between iOS. They will work very much the same. (I wish I knew a good game programming book for iPhone, but all of the ones I open have flaws or bad design that only experienced programmers can get past.

Anywho, if you mix data and images, it usually means to redesign your code